# preg_match_all: Match custom tags

Tags: php, preg-match-all

I'm currently playing around a bit with regular expressions and want to implement some kind of custom tags for texts on a site of mine. For example, if I want to implement a picture into a text, I use the following bracket-tag to do so…

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet **(image: tiger.jpg width: 120 height: 200
>   title: This picture shows a tiger)** sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor
>   invidunt

Now I want my PHP-script to 1. find these bracket-tags and 2. read the single tags in this brackets, so I get some kind of an array like…

```
$attributes = array(
    'image' => 'tiger.jpg',
    'width' => '150',
    'height' => '250',
    'title' => 'This picture shows a tiger',
);
```

The (for me) tricky part about this is that the "values" can contain everything as long it doesn't contain something like `(\w+)\:` – because this is the start of an different tag. The following snippet represents what I have so far – finding the brackets-things works so far, but splitting the bracket-contents into the single tags doesn't really work. I used `(\w+)` for matching the value just as a placeholder – this would not match "tiger.jpg" or "This picture shows a tiger" or something else. I hope you understand what I mean! ;)

```
<?php

$text = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet (image: tiger.jpg width: 150 height: 250 title: This picture shows a tiger) sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt';

// find all tag-groups in brackets
preg_match_all('/\((.*)\)/s', $text, $matches);

// found tags?
if(!empty($matches[0])) {

    // loop through the tags
    foreach($matches[0] as $key => $val) {

        $search = $matches[0][$key]; // this will be replaced later
        $cache = $matches[1][$key]; // this is the tag without brackets

        preg_match_all('/(\w+)\: (\w+)/s', $cache, $list); // find tags in the tag-group (i.e. image, width, …)

        echo '<pre>'.print_r($list, true).'</pre>';

    }

}

?>
```

Would be great if somebody could help me out of this! Thanks! :)

Comment: Can't you use a template library instead of doing this from scratch?

Comment: For sure I could, but I'd prefer to do it myself, as a template-library would be a total overkill of functions which aren't really needed for that simple thing! ;)

Comment: there are some fairly lightweight template libraries around. And bear in mind that one of the biggest problems with this sort of thing is security. Rolling your own templating system has a very strong likelihood of introducing XSS vulnerabilities.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?

$text = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet (image: tiger.jpg width: 150 height: 250 title: This picture shows a tiger) sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt';

// find all tag-groups in brackets
preg_match_all('/\(([^\)]+)\)/s', $text, $matches);
$attributes = array();

// found tags?
if ($matches[0]) {
    $m = preg_split('/\s*(\w+)\:\s+/', $matches[1][0], -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY | PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($m); $i+=2) $attributes[$m[$i]] = $m[$i + 1];
}

var_export($attributes);

/*
array (
  'image' => 'tiger.jpg',
  'width' => '150',
  'height' => '250',
  'title' => 'This picture shows a tiger',
)
*/
```